# Telegram-Bot ReplyKeyboardMarkup shows up in Group for every member

Tags: keyboard, bots, telegram

i am currently working on a Telegram-Bot who has its own Keyboard. Whenever someone writes a /command in a group and the keyboard switches to the custom one, the keyboard switches for every member in this group.

I want to switch it only for the person who wrote the /command.

`customKeyboard.setSelective(true)` doesnt work for me, since the bot is not answering as reply.

Any ideas?